# Find the index of the last true occurrence in a column by row

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following table format:

| id | bool |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | true |
| 2 | true |
| 3 | false |
| 4 | false |
| 5 | false |
| 6 | true |

I'd like it so that I could get another column with the index of the last true occurrence in the bool column by row. If it's true in it's own row then return it's own id. It doesn't sound too hard using a for loop but I want it in a clean pandas format. I.e in this example I would get:

```
column = [1,2,2,2,2,6]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys, shame @Barmar's not good enough to get it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case do

```
df['new'] = df['id'].mul(df['bool']).cummax()
Out[344]: 
0    1
1    2
2    2
3    2
4    2
5    6
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Note that this only works if the ids are monotonously increasing ;)

Comment: I think you mean monotonically.

Answer (score 4):

IIUC, you can mask and `ffill`:

```
df['new'] = df['id'].where(df['bool']).ffill(downcast='infer')
```

output:

```
   id    bool  new
0    1   True    1
1    2   True    2
2    3  False    2
3    4  False    2
4    5  False    2
5    6   True    6
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df1.assign(col1=np.where(df1.bool2,df1.id,pd.NA)).fillna(method='pad')

  id  bool2  col1
0   1   True     1
1   2   True     2
2   3  False     2
3   4  False     2
4   5  False     2
5   6   True     6
```